# How to verify Skype Bot Connector JWT token?

Tags: python, skype, botframework, pyjwt, microsoft-skype-bot

I am trying to verify Authorization token from Microsoft Bot Framework Channel Emulator according to the [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/authentication/#connector---bot-step-3-verify-the-jwt-token).

I retrieve OpenId metadata document from https://api.aps.skype.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration and download keys from https://api.aps.skype.com/v1/keys.

When I send a message from Emulator to my bot, I get a request to */api/messages* with *Authorization* header which contains JWT token. The token header contains this information

```
{
  'alg': 'RS256',
  'kid': 'YbRAQRYcE_motWVJKHrwLBbd_9s',
  'x5t': 'YbRAQRYcE_motWVJKHrwLBbd_9s',
  'typ': 'JWT'
}
```

According to the *kid* value, I choose this JWK key

```
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "kid": "YbRAQRYcE_motWVJKHrwLBbd_9s",
  "x5t": "YbRAQRYcE_motWVJKHrwLBbd_9s",
  "n": "vbcFrj193Gm6zeo5e2_y54Jx49sIgScv-2JO-n6NxNqQaKVnMkHcz-S1j2FfpFngotwGMzZIKVCY1SK8SKZMFfRTU3wvToZITwf3W1Qq6n-h-abqpyJTaqIcfhA0d6kEAM5NsQAKhfvw7fre1QicmU9LWVWUYAayLmiRX6o3tktJq6H58pUzTtx_D0Dprnx6z5sW-uiMipLXbrgYmOez7htokJVgDg8w-yDFCxZNo7KVueUkLkxhNjYGkGfnt18s7ZW036WoTmdaQmW4CChf_o4TLE5VyGpYWm7I_-nV95BBvwlzokVVKzveKf3l5UU3c6PkGy-BB3E_ChqFm6sPWw",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "x5c": ["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"],
  "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0"
}
```

For token verification I use [pyjwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt). And here I don't know what key to use for token verification in jwt.decode() function.

```
jwt.decode(token, key=key_from_skype_com)
```

For both *n* and *x5c* fields I tried these options:

- pass them as is out of desperation
- base64url-decode them
- base64url-decode them and load with load_der_public_key() function from [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/) package

Cryptography code

```
from cryptography.hazmat import backends
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
serialization.load_der_public_key(decoded_key, backend=backends.default_backend())
```

It seems that *n* field of JWK is base64-urlsafe encoded and *x5c* is just base64 encoded. So I decoded them appropriately.

I am not a cryptography expert. I tried searching MS documentation which mostly contain examples on using their SDK for Node.js and C#. And I read [RFC 7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4) and [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1) but found no specific information.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem in [this pull-request](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/pull/202). I will edit question and add a proper answer later.